# Strange characters preceding and following HTML in HTTP request

Tags: http, c++-cx

## Background

I am building a custom HTTP parser in C++/CX using sockets. As such, I have full control over the entire HTTP request and response.

## Request

```
GET /posts/html-android-app?referrer=rss HTTP/1.1
Host: mixturatech.com
Connection: close
```

## Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2015 04:44:59 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: public
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

6a2f
<!DOCTYPE html>
[trimmed document content]
</html>
0
```

## Additional Data

If I navigate to the webpage with Chrome, WireShark captures the same data that I am seeing (with extraneous characters), yet Chrome manages to trim that content out. (I am looking at Chrome's data in the Network tab in Developer Tools.)

I do not see this problem on every site I retrieve, but the problem, if it exists, seems to be sitewide.

## Questions

- What is up with the `6a2f` and `0` preceding and following the document?
- Is this an encoding issue?
- Is there some way that I can positively identify, without hardcoding boundaries for the document, such as it must start with `<` and end with `>`, where the actual content lies?
- Will those characters, if they exist in a page, always be limited to length 4 and 1 respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "chunked transfer encoding". Read http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#chunked.encoding.